# Determine the spectrum of the operator: $T:C[0,1] \to C[0,1], (Tx)(t) = x(t^2)$

Tags: functional-analysis

This is a problem in my homework that I can not work it out.

I only know that $\|T\| = 1$ thus $\sigma(T) \subset \{\lambda, \lambda \leq 1\}$. What should I do next?

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I will only supply hints.

1) Find the inverse of T. What can you tell about its spectrum, and does this tell you anything about the spectrum of T?

2) Show that 1 is an eigenvalue of T.

3) In order to show that $\lambda$ is in the spectrum of T, it suffices to show, for all $\epsilon>0$, that there is some $x$ with $\|(T-\lambda)x\|\leq\epsilon\|x\|$.